# In Android, using java: determine string length of mix-bytes character String?

Tags: java, android

There is a  String variable containing ascii characters and double bytes characters(for example, the Chinese, Japanese,...).

How to decide the total length of the String ? Also, I want to implement with the string substring/replace function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other's have said, Java Strings are conceptually read-only arrays of Java characters, and the "length" of a String is the number of characters.  However, there are complicating issues:

- A Java character is not necessarily what you think of as a character.  In particular, there are more Unicode characters (code-points) than can be represented using Java characters.  Some Unicode code-points require two Java characters to represent them.  (This is the "extended plane" issue that Thilo refers to.)
- Some JVMs (with the appropriate JVM flags set at startup) will use a String representation where the characters are encoded in UTF-8.  While the length of the String is the same (in this case, the number of Java characters represented by the UTF-8), the memory used can be significantly less.

Then there is the question of how many bytes are required to represent the String's characters as UTF-8, or in some other encoding.  As far as I know, the only JVM provided way to find that out is to do the conversion; e.g. using `getBytes(charSet)`.

Finally, there is the question of how many bytes a String occupies in the heap.  You can find out how many bytes are in the `String` object and its associated `char[]` backing object.  However, predicting what that is going to be can be tricky, when you consider that `substring` and other `String` methods can create sets of strings that *share* a single backing array.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen and I have learned much about Java's String/characters today ! However, I am not have a solid idea : If I have get the numbe of bytes of the String and then want to cut/shorten the length of String if its length(total bytes) is longer beyond the length limittion. if the UTF-8 String is a mixed-bytes String, for example, the strring is composed as: "sDDsDsDDDDss"(s:1 byte character, D:2 bytes chacater). The str.substring(start, end)  method seems can not meet the purpose. Please correct me If I am wrong, tks !

Comment: @cmh - the `substring(...)` method use character offsets not byte offsets.  The only way you can do byte-wise indexing or other operations on a String is to convert it into a byte array first.  The String API uses character offsets not byte offsets ... even in the special case I mentioned in the 2nd bullet point.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply ! I understanded. And it seems there is not a easy way or API to handle the mixed-bytes String. So, I think I have to develpe a method by myself. Any way, thanks again for the support !

Comment: @cmh - You are still mischaracterizing the problem.  Your problem is that you want to treat a string like an array of bytes, when it is actually like an array of characters.  If you think of your "s"'s and "DD"'s as characters then the String API works just fine.

Answer (score 6):

The string type in Java is implicitly UTF-16. All other encodings (e.g. UTF-8) should be represented using `byte` arrays.

"Length" is an ambiguous term.

Each Unicode code point will consume one or two code *units* (16-bit `char`s) - the basic multilingual plane and the supplementary ranges. When transcoded to different encodings, the number of bytes a string will consume can change. A sequence of code points can also combine to form a single user-visible grapheme.

So, here are ways to measure the "length" of a string:

- number of bytes: [String.getBytes(Charset).length](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29)
- number of chars: [String.length()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29)
- number of code points: [String.codePointCount(int,int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#codePointCount%28int,%20int%29)
- number of graphemes: [BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance(Locale)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/BreakIterator.html#getCharacterInstance%28java.util.Locale%29)

*I covered some of this in [a blog post](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html).*

---

> Comment: And is there an easy way/API to handle the mix-bytes String?
>   (to cut/shorten/substring() the string like "sDDsssDDDDsDD" (s:single
>   byte ascii character, DD:double bytes character)?

Consider the Java string literal `"Hello 您好世界"` which can also be expressed as `"Hello \u60a8\u597d\u4e16\u754c"`.

This could be encoded in the legacy Windows [Simplified Chinese](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/cc305153) double-byte encoding as the byte sequence:

```
48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 c4 fa ba c3 ca c0 bd e7
```

In order to turn this into Java characters, you would decode it:

```
byte[] data = { 0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x20, (byte) 0xc4,
    (byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xca, (byte) 0xc0,
    (byte) 0xbd, (byte) 0xe7 };
Charset encoding = Charset.forName("x-mswin-936");
String hello = new String(data, encoding);
```

Now that you've transcoded the data to Unicode, you can use the usual string manipulation mechanisms ([substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29), [regex matching](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29), etc.).

Note that you must know the double-byte encoding you use before transformation. If you don't know the encoding, all you have is junk.

I don't know what encodings Android supports, but you can discover this at runtime by calling [Charset.availableCharsets()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#availableCharsets%28%29). If Android doesn't support an encoding you need, have a look at the [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/) library.

Comment: thaks for reply ! And is there an easy way/API to handle the mix-bytes String? (to cut/shorten/substring() the string like "sDDsssDDDDsDD" (s:single byte ascii character, DD:double bytes character)?

Comment: Character data should be a single encoding, though many are supersets of US-ASCII.

Answer (score 4):

Java strings are Characters, not bytes. The length is the number of characters. If you want the number of bytes, use

`str.getBytes(encoding).length`

where encoding is e.g. "UTF-8".

Answer (score 0):

Java uses Unicode internally, so it doesn't matter what the actually characters are. `String.length()` will give you the correct length. Same goes for other String methods.

Comment: except for Unicode characters from the "extended plane" that take up more than one "character" ;-(