# Android EditText, get characters as shown (combined - Asian, Arabic, etc)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I don't know the correct name for this, but lots of languages will combine several characters into 1 unique character. When I get the text from the EditText by getText() or getEditableText(), this is still just a sequence of single characters as entered. Is it possible to get an exact character sequence from an EditText as it is displayed?

Regards

Comment: You should try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/11030384/2194831

Comment: Is this mixed byte / extended-plane problem the issue here? I have a bad feeling that Android has some kind of post-processor to handle some specific language cases, rather than some specific character to represent each possibility. Is this the case or is there still a way to do this? Long story short for what I want to achieve - I am drawing each new character entered into an EditText to a TextPaint, then drawing a bitmap representation of the text by rendering each bitmap character.